# Issues using ggplot2 aes_string with box plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I seem to be having problems using ggplot2.

I get the following error while trying to plot box plots with the aes_string:

> Error: stat_boxplot requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y

Here is an example:

```
x='group'
y='value'
df=data.frame(group=c('A','A','B','B','C','C'),value=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
ggplot(data=df,aes_string(x,y)) + geom_boxplot() #returns the error
ggplot(data=df,aes(x,y)) + geom_boxplot() #plots nonsense (naturally)
ggplot(data=df,aes(group,value)) + geom_boxplot() #works, but not strings
```

Any suggestions on how I can make this work with strings?

Comment: -1 for crossposting without reference: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ggplot2/p4EFpLKqQMc/discussion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`aes` allows the first two arguments to be unnamed and are assumed to be x and y (respectively); `aes_string` does not have this shortcut, and so all arguments must be named.
Try:

```
ggplot(data=df,aes_string(x='group',y='value')) + geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: The only question is - why?

Comment: `ggplot(data=df, aes_string(x=x,y=y)) + geom_boxplot()` also works.

Comment: `aes` allows the first two arguments to be unnamed and are assumed to be x and y (respectively); `aes_string` does not have this shortcut, and so all arguments must be named.